# What are the "credits" of this background music in "SG-1: Beachhead"?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, music-identification

Not sure this is the right place to ask, since the question isn't really about the sci-fi plot. I'm looking for the "credits" (title, composer, etc.) of a piece of music in an episode of *Stargate SG-1*. Unfortunately [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0709046/soundtrack?ref_=tt_trv_snd) only shows the credits for the main and the end title (the same for each episode):

- Main Title: Written by Joel Goldsmith and David Arnold
- End Title: Written by Joel Goldsmith

But I'm interested in the following background music [starting around the 6th minute into the episode](https://youtu.be/oXqOmm4KKhI?t=31).

I would like to know if the title was composed for that specific scene or taken from a repository and/or belongs to an existing soundtrack, or at least who composed it.

Comment: The only musical credit is Joel Goldsmith

Comment: @Valorum yes, and that's to the main/end title, as I've written in my question, not to the background music

Comment: As far as I'm aware that *includes* the incidental music in the show.

Comment: @Albin Forgot you posted this... I meant to pull up the episode online to check it out... have you tried sound hound or anything by any chance or is there other sound effects drowning out that opportunity?

Comment: @Odin1806 no, I haven't tried sound hound yet, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @user14111 I'm not a native speaker, so maybe I don't use it in the right context... not sure. Actually I'm looking for the song itself, so I will need the composer, title etc. That's what I originally meant by "credentials"...

Answer (score 1):

There is no title.

This is part of the episode's incidental score which, according to [the full credits](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0709046/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast), was composed by Neal Acree and Joel Goldsmith.

To my knowledge, this track never made it onto a soundtrack release.

It [almost certainly] did not come from a third-party musical repository.

Comment: Those credits also include David Arnold as 'composer: original themes'.

Comment: Good points, thank you for your answer. It still would be interessted to find out if the track has specifically been composed for the episode or if it has been taken from a repository.

Comment: @Jontia That's not relevant to the incidental score.

Comment: @Albin It was composed for the episode, as part of the episode's original incidental score, by the above named composers, who were on the production team of the show. Like almost every other cue in the show (most shows!) ;)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings interesting... thanks. out of curiosity, where did you get this inside information?

Comment: @Albin It's not inside information, but common knowledge. This is how incidental music is produced for television shows.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings interesting...  generally I would agree, but I also heard differently (that's what initially triggered the part about the repositry in my question). When I was taking after work classes a fellow student of mine (he was a sound "technician", choosing background sound and the "in-between music" for various shows for a entertainment studio/network) told me that they have of huge music archive from which he can choose various sounds. But I don't remember what kind of network that was, so I'm not sure if it applies here.

Comment: @Albin: That's not the same as a produced television show. Yes, the surrounding programming will usually involve generic beds and samples, which could be produced in-house or sourced from a repository. It would be uneconomical to compose original scores for that type of programming.